# How do I process an individual cube partition

Tags: ssas, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got a cube set up with a number of partitions - one for each year of data in my fact table. I'd like to process partitions on an individual basis. Is this possible? If so, how do I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to process a individual partition manually is the SQL Server Management Studio, where you can simply right-click any partition and select "Process". I guess this is not what you want.

How do you process your cube in the first place? If you use SSIS for instance, you could use a script transformation to generate an XMLA script that processes the individual partition. In the simplest form the script would only take an existing XMLA and replace the name of the partition with the correct value. We have done this in a project and it works very well. The generated script can the be executed with the SSIS XMLA task as well.

If you explain your requirements in more detail maybe I can help you better.

Nicolas

Comment: D'Oh! Thanks Nicolas, I was working in BIDS, so I figured I could do it right in there, it never occurred to me to do it in SSMS. Do you know if there's a way to do it in BIDS?

Comment: Is there a way to issue the XMLA from TSQL?

Answer (score 4):

you can also do it from BIDS, go to the Partitions tab of your cube, locate the partition you want to process, right click on it and you'll see an option

Comment: Ah, perfect... both answers are useful, sadly I've already accepted the other answer... +1 though, thank you.

Comment: I gave a plus to your answer in exchange :-)